# Show music not albums - Steam Music

Tags: steam

Steam just rolled out a new update for all clients adding a few features and one of them being Steam Music. It adds functionality to listen to music from games (purchased as a extra DLC). My question is, by default it is sorted *by albums* is there a way to *show a list of all songs what Steam has found* or are in it's database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only *Albums*, *Artists*, and *Playlists* are supported at this time. However, you could accomplish something of this sort by creating a playlist of all your songs.

To do this, first make sure you're in *Albums* view:
[image: Albums view]

Then right click on the first album and select *Add to Playlist* > *New Playlist*:
[image: Add to Playlist > New Playlist]

Then do the same for every album in the list, but add it to the existing playlist instead of creating a new one each time.

Then go to *Playlists* view:
[image: Playlists view]

Right click the playlist and select *Rename*:
[image: Rename]

Then call it something like "Library".

Now you have a list of your whole library that you can look through and play specific songs, or double click it to start from the top. You will have to keep this updated by adding all the new albums you get to this playlist. This is the best available method until a *Songs* view is actually implemented.

Comment: I have a playlist with all my songs, any idea's how to play it?

Comment: @Sebie See my updated answer with instructions.

Comment: Yup just looking at it now @Keavon, could you edit it or add somewhere that you can't play through steam external playlists other then that, thank you for explaining this, accepted as answer and +1 !

Comment: @Sebie I'm actually not sure if Steam supports external playlists, but this answer is meant to not have to use external software.

Comment: It's ok, must have been my misunderstanding. Anyways thanks for the answer got it all working with your method!